# XML to JSON Conversion incorrect output

Tags: java, json, xml, converters

I have converted an XML string to JSON but although the formatting is correct, some data changed during the process.

I've used a method that is preferred by many people:

```
JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString();
```

I've checked the resulting XML and it's completed and perfect, however after it went through the "toJSONObject" method some numeric values have changed...

For instance one of the values that is supposed to return is a String "0000000000623" but it returns as Integer 408.

Any ideas on how to solve this or any other method that I could use?

Comment: before(xml) and after(json) samples?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't "0623" give you 403?  (not 408)

It looks like whatever library you have doing the processing is recognizing the leading 0 characters as indicating octal (base 8) encoding.

Comment: you're right, it was 403. However it shouldn't be converting octals and decimals. Bottom line is glassfish is to blame, when i publish my project through tomcat, the xml to json is processed perfectly. No the question would be, why would it work with tomcat and not glassfish?

Comment: Many string to integer parsers interpret a leading '0x' as meaning base 16 (hexadecimal), a leading '0' as meaning base 8 (octal), and all others as base 10 (decimal).  This is historic; it has been done this way for at least four decades.  (That doesn't mean it is good or that it doesn't cause unintentional errors)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal#In_computers